# What are logging best practices - FastAPI and Azure Functions

Tags: logging, azure-functions, fastapi

I started at a new job with a Web App built on Python FastAPI and React. We run server-less on Azure Functions. I noticed there is no proper logging happening and wanted to implement it.
However when I asked some of the other devs I got mixed responses.

1. Azure Functions has its own built-in logging. I am not 100% sure how to access it in a useful way or whether it is available on local debugging (run using azure-functions-core-tools)
2. FastAPI apparently has built-in logging. When running the app in the console we get a whole lot of output including query calls and sometimes even durations (See excerpt appended).

All this happens sort of behind the scenes and I miss my well-known `logger.log(INFO, "Hey there")` kind of logging. One senior said logging will just slow down the app.
Is this no longer good practice or should I push to have it added or use the inherent logging available and maybe persist that? Or something else? Maybe I am missing something completely.
And if I do push to implement logging, what should I look at? Logging into a DB or local text file or Redis or any other solution (opinions welcome).

```
Local console log excerpt:
Request successfully matched the route with name 'orders' and template '/api/orders/{*route}'
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.414Z] Executing 'Functions.orders' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=168d2tee-4cff-4886-99ed-fa494c140f4f)
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.419Z] [channel] received 91d88tcd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-69572d1e6ab3: RpcLog
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.419Z] Received FunctionInvocationRequest, request ID: batt1a3-bb47-4c81-b456-43da2t8fed033, function ID: ff09tt12-67e9-49e9-985e-180e3d352a44, function name: orders, invocation ID: 168d2tee-4cff-4886-99ed-fa494c140f4f, function type: sync, sync threadpool max workers: 1000
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.420Z] [channel] received 91dt8ecd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-69572a1e6ab3: RpcLog
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.431Z] handle() is deprecated. Please `await .handle_async()` instead.
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.634Z] [channel] received 91dt8ecd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-69572d1e6ab3: RpcLog
[2023-09-15T07:21:32.635Z] query: [Select Count(*) AS TOTAL FROM ( SELECT "OM"."ORDER_NUMBER", "OM"."TRANSACTION_RE...]
[2023-09-15T07:21:33.775Z] [channel] received 91d88ecd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-69t72d1e6ab3: RpcLog
[2023-09-15T07:21:33.776Z] query execution done
[2023-09-15T07:21:33.781Z] [channel] received 91d88ecd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-697td1e6ab3: RpcLog
[2023-09-15T07:21:33.782Z] query: [SELECT DISTINCT "MAIN"."ORDER_NUMBER", "MAIN"."TRANSACTION_REF", "MAIN"."TRANSPO...]
[2023-09-15T07:21:34.397Z] [channel] received 91d88ecd-da6e-47f3-b9f5-69572d1e6ab3: RpcLog
Executed 'Functions.orders' (Succeeded, Id=a69bb19e-0e9d-4892-af5a-ac8bcc26b31d, Duration=1587m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging is a part of any application, and it is good practice to implement it. Azure Functions has its own built-in logging. You can stream logs for functions in near real-time using Azure Monitor Logs[ You can also connect your function app to Application Insights for monitoring and configure data collection. You can use the logging statement specific to your language to generate custom logs.

- Azure Functions has built-in logging, which is often for serverless applications. Azure Functions logging can be configured to send logs to different destinations, including Application Insights, Azure Monitor, or storage accounts. To access logs during local debugging using azure-functions-core-tools, you can check the terminal or console where you started the debugging session. You can configure the log level and other settings in your `host.json` file.
- Where FastAPI does have its own logging system. When you run your FastAPI application in development mode, it provides detailed logs about request handling, route matching, and more. This built-in logging is useful for debugging and understanding the application's behavior. You can configure the log level in FastAPI by setting the `log_level` parameter when creating your FastAPI app.

This is the sample example with logging in Flask with Azure function from this [reference](https://github.com/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/tree/main/).

```py
@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def get_name(name: str):
    logger.info(f"Received a request to /hello/{name}")
    return {
        "name": name,
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info! The breakdown really helps, there were so many logs I did not know where they all came from. I have now accessed the prod logs on Azure and local logs just on console output, though we might choose to persist them in the near future.
Thanks again!